# Afnetworking magical record and appropriate use

Tags: ios, core-data, afnetworking, magicalrecord

I am building à news app based on AFNetworking and MagicalRecord.
I havé to perform à background synchronisation With à server in order to 
1) retrieve existing categories
2) for each category retrieve All articles.

So i am using a nsoperationqueue in which i add all afnetworking operation i need.
I am creating a dispatch queue and set it as the successqueue of all afnetworking operations so the completion blocks are not performed in the main thread.

At the end of the synchronization, i am performing a save so all data are saved in the perisitent store.

I am encountering the following issues:
Relationships cannot be established as articles and categories are created in different threads: i always have an exception.
When and how should i save my core data objects?
After reading thousands of articles on magicalrecord i am completely lost pn this point.

Thank you to all the ios master of this wonderful site :)

Comment: Have you considered RestKit?

Comment: I was not aware of this framework but after having a quick look to it it seems I cannot use it because the server side is not Rest at all :(

Comment: Posting code example would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I understood what I was doing wrong.

Using MagicalRecord in separated threads was the point as MagicalRecord creates a different NSManagedContext for different threads.

After deep reading of Apple documentation on CoreData and multiple threads, I point out that working on different threads can be done on same NSManagedContext if you can ensure that none of the objects will be affected simultaneously.

So by using a sequential dispatch_queue, with a dedicated and single NSManagedObjectContext, it did the job.

Hope this can help others.